# A reporter from patches in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I need that each patch identifies its color and count the number of patches with the same color.I tried with:

```
ask patches [count patches with pcolor = [pcolor] of myself]
```

But, this is not correct. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error with the `with` - it needs the next section to be in [] (so that it asks whether the contents are true or false). Also, you haven't told patches what to do with the number once it's calculated. Have a look at this:

```
patches-own [count-same]

to setup
  let pcol-list (list red blue green)
  ask patches [set pcolor one-of pcol-list]
  ask patches
  [set count-same count patches with [pcolor = [pcolor] of myself]]
end
```

Comment: I'd suggest `one-of pcol-list` instead of `item random 3 pcol-list`... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Jen's answer is the correct one.

That being said, I'd like to point out the existence of a very useful reporter primitive from the `table` extension: [`table:counts`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/table.html#table:counts).

You can use it to do exactly what you need. It takes a list of items, counts the number of occurrences of each item, and puts the results in a handy table with those items as keys and the counts as values. In your case, the "list of items" is the list of the `pcolor` of all the patches.

Here is how you would use it:

```
extensions [ table ]
patches-own [ count-same ]

to setup
  ask patches [ set pcolor one-of base-colors ]
  let color-counts table:counts [ pcolor ] of patches  
  ask patches [ set count-same table:get color-counts pcolor ]    
end
```

The main advantage compared to your original code is that it is that it would be *much* faster (though you might not notice it if your number of patches is small).

The reason for this is that your code has to count the number of patches of the same color again for every single patch, so the running time is proportional to the square of the number of patches. Its complexity is *O*(*n*²), in computer science lingo.

The `table:count` primitive, on the other hand, only goes through the list of colors once and adds +1 into the right "bucket" each time it sees a color. It has linear complexity: *O*(*n*).